# Statistics - Standard deviation and margin of error question

Tags: statistics

Would you mind clarifying the difference between SD and MOE in the context of these two problems? 
For the first one I had to subtract 230 from 250, then divide by 4 to get the correct answer 5.
For the second problem I subtracted 25 from 35, and divided by 2. 
Why did the first problem (SD) require me to divide by 4? 
--- Thanks

First:  The distribution of gestation duration (length of pregnancy in days) for chimpanzees is normally distributed with a mean score of 240 days. Given 95% of chimpanzee pregnancies last 230 to 250 days, which of the following is most likely to be the standard deviation of the distribution?

Second:  According to Webmd.com, a 95% confidence interval for the true mean weight gain (lbs.) during pregnancy for a pregnant person is given by (25, 35). What is the margin of error?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are using confidence intervals (CIs) of the type
$$\bar X \pm 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$$

Then the standard deviation is $\sigma$ and the standard error
is $\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$

So, roughly speaking you divide the length of the CI by 2 to get
the margin of error. So that takes care of the second problem.

In the first problem, you have given incomplete information and I can
only speculate: You have a CI of length 20 and margin of
error of 10. If you have $10/2 = (1.96/\sqrt{n})\sigma,$ you must
be taking $n$ into account. What value of $n$ gives $\sigma=5?$
(Maybe they want you to approximate $1.96 \approx 2.$)